# Get values of a field on previous dates

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with the following data.

| fecha | SearchPhrase | url | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword1 | url1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword2 | url2 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword1 | url1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword3 | url3 | 3 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword4 | url4 | 7 |
| 2022-02-28 | keyword1 | url1 | 3 |
| 2022-02-28 | keyword1 | url1 | 4 |
| 2022-02-28 | keyword2 | url2 | 3 |
| 2022-02-27 | keyword1 | url1 | 3 |
| 2022-02-27 | keyword2 | url2 | 5 |
| 2022-02-27 | keyword3 | url3 | 10 |

Each word can have two values on the same day (I only want the lower one) and a word may not exist on some date.

I want to get, for each word that exists on the last date, the current rank and the previous date's minimum value for each word.

Result desired

| fecha | SearchPhrase | currentRank | previusRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword3 | 3 | 10 |
| 2022-03-01 | keyword4 | 7 |  |

I'm using this query

```
WITH (SELECT max(fecha)
        FROM tableName)AS InitDate
SELECT
    t1.sDate,
    t1.SearchPhrase,
    argMin(ranking, t1.sDate) AS rankDate1,
    any(t2.ranking) AS rankDate2,
    max(t2.sDate) AS Date2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        fecha AS sDate,
       kw as  SearchPhrase,
        any(rank) AS ranking
    FROM tableName
    WHERE fecha = InitDate
    GROUP BY
        fecha,
        SearchPhrase
    ORDER BY
        fecha DESC,
        ranking ASC
) AS t1
any LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        fecha,
      kw as  SearchPhrase,
        any(rank) AS ranking,
        any(fecha) AS sDate
    FROM tableName
    WHERE fecha < InitDate
    GROUP BY
        fecha,
        SearchPhrase
    ORDER BY
        fecha DESC,
        ranking ASC
) AS t2 USING (SearchPhrase)
GROUP BY
    sDate,
    SearchPhrase
LIMIT 10
```

But I'm sure it can be done better

Comment: Not an answer, but look into using the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` analytic functions.

Comment: I don't know "LEAD()" function in clickhouse

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/lag-lead/

Answer (score 1):

The basic building block, that I've used to address this problem, extracts the minimum value for each "SearchPhrase":

```
(
SELECT 
    fecha,
    SearchPhrase,
    MIN(`rank`)     AS currentRank
FROM 
    search_infos
GROUP BY
    SearchPhrase,
    fecha
) min_ranks
```

Given the information contained in this table, I've considered two ways of solving this problem:

- Using a `LAG`/`LEAD` window function, which allows you to retrieve the previous/next value in the time-series (either date or rank value) - as already suggested in the comments. As you can see from the snippet below, the LEAD value allows us to gather the leading rank value, while the `ROW_NUMBER` is useful to impose a ranking on dates, where the rank=1 will represent the minimum value of date for each "SearchPhrase".

  ```
  SELECT
      fecha,
      SearchPhrase,
      currentRank,
      previusRank
  FROM (
      SELECT 
          fecha,
          SearchPhrase,
          currentRank,
          LEAD(currentRank) OVER(
              PARTITION BY SearchPhrase 
              ORDER BY     fecha DESC
          )                   AS previusRank,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY SearchPhrase 
              ORDER BY     fecha DESC
          )                   AS fecha_order
      FROM min_ranks 
  ) curr_and_prec_ranks
  WHERE
      fecha_order = 1
  ```

  Fiddle Link: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xy65u37m.
- Using a `JOIN` to match current date and previous date for each SearchPhrase. In this case the `ROW_NUMBER` is always used to keep track of the ranking on the dates and what we do is joining the same table with itself where the values of "SearchPhrase" correspond and at the same time their date rank difference is 1. The final filtering on `curr.fecha_order = 1` is useful to select the last date.

  ```
  WITH min_ranks_with_fecha_order AS (
      SELECT 
          *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
              PARTITION BY SearchPhrase 
              ORDER BY     fecha DESC
          )                   AS fecha_order
      FROM min_ranks
  )
  SELECT 
      curr.fecha,
      curr.SearchPhrase,
      curr.currentRank        AS current_rank,
      prec.currentRank        AS previus_rank
  FROM 
      min_ranks_with_fecha_order curr
  LEFT JOIN 
      min_ranks_with_fecha_order prec
  ON 
      curr.SearchPhrase = prec.SearchPhrase
  AND
      curr.fecha_order = prec.fecha_order-1
  WHERE 
      curr.fecha_order = 1
  ```

  Fiddle Link: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xy5rcsw3.

Comment: Thanks @limon but doesn't work 

First query: "DB::Exception: Can't infer common type for joined columns: fecha_order: UInt64 at left, minus(prec.fecha_order, 1): Int64 at right. There is no supertype for types Int64, UInt64 because some of them are signed integers and some are unsigned integers, but there is no signed integer type, that can exactly represent all required unsigned integer values. (TYPE_MISMATCH)"

And second: " DB::Exception: Unknown aggregate function LEAD. (UNKNOWN_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION)"

I think Clickhouse doesn't support LEAD function